Unity MonoBehaviour Lifecycle: When are Start() and Update() Called for an Instance Created in Update()?
When you instantiate a new MonoBehaviour within another MonoBehaviour's Update() method, When will the lifecycle methods of the new MonoBehaviour be called according to Unity's execution order?
For example, if you instantiate in frame A, Start() will be invoked in frame B, and Update() will start from frame C.

Tbh you could fairly easily find out yourself:
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            var x = new GameObject("X");
            x.AddComponent<SubTest>();
                
            var y = new GameObject("Y");
            y.AddComponent<SubTest>();
        }
    }

    private class SubTest : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Awake()
        {
            Debug.Log($"{name} Awake: {Time.frameCount}");
        }
            
        private void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log($"{name} Start: {Time.frameCount}");
        }

        private bool firstUpdate;
            
        private void Update()
        {
            if (firstUpdate)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
                return;
            }
                
            firstUpdate = true;
            Debug.Log($"{name} First Update: {Time.frameCount}");
        }
    }
}

=>
X Awake: 3
Y Awake: 3
X Start: 3
Y Start: 3
X First Update: 4
Y First Update: 4

So as you can see

Awake is called right away

OnEnable is called right away after Awake

Start is delayed until the end of the current frame
This is quite useful and allows you to e.g. adjust public fields and properties before Start uses them
Note that this only applies within a script type scope so to scripts of the same type and the API does not guarantee this in general:

For objects that are part of a scene asset, Awake and OnEnable functions for all scripts are called before Start and subsequent functions are called for any of them. However, this can’t be enforced when you instantiate an object at runtime.

(so far it was always the case for me though)

Update is first called in the next frame after instantiation


